# If the shaliach tzibur is reciting birchot hashachar, and you are in the middle of putting on your tefillin, can you answer amen to his brachot?

Tags: tefilin, amen, tefillah-betzibbur

It's very common in minyan for people to still be putting on their tefillin when the shaliach tzibur begins davening. I always answer amen to birchot hashachar. I was somewhat surprised when another member of the minyan told me that I shouldn't, because I was not supposed to talk while putting on tefillin. I thought that applied to having conversations, but not to answering amen.

Answer (score 0):

you're not allowed to say amen in between saying the bracha for the tefillin shel yad and the bracha for the tefillin shel rosh.

[https://torah.org/learning/mishna-berura-s25/#:~:text=MB%2035%3A%20He%20should%20not,answer%20%E2%80%9Camen%E2%80%9D%20before%20putting%20on](https://torah.org/learning/mishna-berura-s25/#:%7E:text=MB%2035%3A%20He%20should%20not,answer%20%E2%80%9Camen%E2%80%9D%20before%20putting%20on)

Comment: Chabad holds you can interrupt for borchu, kedusha, etc., and make a separate bracha on the shel rosh.

Comment: @shmosel for barchu yes, not for all parts of kaddish, and not for other brachos such as birchas hashachar